# Convert cell value to DateTime

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a row of cells in Excel filled with datetimes in the following messy format: `July 13, 2016 at 12:10AM`. I want to convert this to `2016/07/13 12:10` ('yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm' in the 24h format). Can I do this using a formula or should I write a vba code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

First you must remove the `at`

Second you need a space between the time and the `AM` or `PM`

The follow formula will turn it into a date/time:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"at",""),"AM"," AM"),"PM"," PM")
```

Then you can format the cell with the custom format:

```
yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm
```

[image]

Comment: @jeroen please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.